# why use fresco datasource to get bitmap is empty

Tags: android, facebook, fresco

Why is bitmap returned in `onNewResultImpl` null?

```
final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById (R.id.imageView);

ImageRequest request = ImageRequest.fromUri(pic_uri);

ImagePipeline imagePipeline = Fresco.getImagePipeline();
DataSource dataSource = imagePipeline.fetchEncodedImage(request, this);
CloseableReference<CloseableImage> imageReference = null;
dataSource.subscribe (new BaseBitmapDataSubscriber() {
    @Override
    protected void onNewResultImpl(Bitmap bitmap) {
        LogUtils._d("onNewResultImpl....");
        if(bitmap == null) {
            LogUtils._d("bitmap is null");
        }
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFailureImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
        LogUtils._d("onFailureImpl....");
    }
}, CallerThreadExecutor.getInstance());
```

Comment: are you getting any error?if so post your logcat.or else have you checked your datasource is that null or there is something in that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have made some modification to make things work in your code, consider using this. I have also tested it and it worked all fine.

```
// To get image using Fresco
ImageRequest imageRequest = ImageRequestBuilder
          .newBuilderWithSource( Uri.parse(getFeedItem(position).feedImageUrl.get(index)))
          .setProgressiveRenderingEnabled(true)
          .build();

ImagePipeline imagePipeline = Fresco.getImagePipeline();
DataSource<CloseableReference<CloseableImage>> dataSource = 
                              imagePipeline.fetchDecodedImage(imageRequest,mContext);

 dataSource.subscribe(new BaseBitmapDataSubscriber() {

     @Override
     public void onNewResultImpl(@Nullable Bitmap bitmap) {
         // You can use the bitmap in only limited ways
         // No need to do any cleanup.
     }

     @Override
     public void onFailureImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
         // No cleanup required here.
     }

 }, CallerThreadExecutor.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: You are using `fetchEncodedImage` rather than `fetchDecodedImage`. That means that every image returns will have no underlying bitmap. But if you change that to `fetchDecodedImage` and still see null Bitmaps, it will be because of what I have written about below.

See the source code here: https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/master/imagepipeline/src/main/java/com/facebook/imagepipeline/datasource/BaseBitmapDataSubscriber.java#L57-L61

Not all images that are returned are `CloseableBitmap`s, and those that are not do not have an underlying bitmap to return, so this method returns a null Bitmap.

Comment: hi Binnie, just like you said: closeableImageRef.get() returns instance of CloseableAnimatedImage, not CloseableBitmap, so the Bitmap returned is null. Is there a way to show this image?

Answer (score 3):

You should call `fetchDecodedImage,` not `fetchEncodedImage,` if you need a Bitmap.